# how to select data when i use from fulltext and inner join?

Tags: mysql, join, full-text-search, inner-join

I have two tables and  i want select data two tables with inner join that it work true. but my problem is in out of query

```
SELECT 
  TBL_USERSMETA.NAME,
  TBL_USERSMETA.FAMILY,
  TBL_USERS.* 
  FROM TBL_USERSMETA 
  INNER JOIN
    TBL_USERS 
      ON TBL_USERSMETA.ID 
      AND TBL_USERS.ID In (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM TBL_USERS 
        WHERE MATCH(USERNAME) AGAINST('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

problem :
[image]

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please [edit] your question and add the desired output to make it more clear.

Comment: Please Precision to code and out of code in pic.repeat id ,...

Comment: You seem to have some trouble expressing yourself in English. Don't worry. You can use [google translate](http://translate.google.com/#fa/en/). Write in your own language and post the translation.

Comment: User name and ID in the output is repeated

Comment: And you want to do a fulltext search in the username field for stuff starting with a?

Comment: yes,i want to do a fulltext search in the username field for stuff starting with a .

Comment: Look at the rest of your columns. Looks like `TBL_USERSMETA` might have two lines per user id.